# iOS Autolayout: Handling different screen heights

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am desperatly trying to get to grips with Autolayout and need advice on how best to approach handling the following scenario. I am working with an existing design that I need to lay out appropriately so it will function on any iPhone screen size.

For each screen, I have identified a section of the app that should partially expand/collapse to compensate for the difference in screen height. I have illustrated this in the image below. Primarily, is this the best way to approach the problem?

[image: example layout]

Assuming this is the best way to approach the problem, how should constraints be added to fix the positioning and heights of views 1,2 & 4, while allowing view 2 and it's content to flex in accordance with the device view height?

I have experimented profusely with constraits and have been unable to achieve the illustrated outcome.

Comment: show us where you have been stuck... maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would have done it.

**All views:**

- Align the leading and trailing space to the superview

**View 1:**

- Align the top to the superview or top layout guide
- Add a fixed height

**View 4:**

- Align the bottom to the superview or bottom layout guide
- Add a fixed height

**View 3:**

- Align the bottom to view 4 (using vertical spacing)
- Add a fixed height

**View 2:**

- Align the top to view 1
- Align the bottom to view 3

Comment: This answer is nicely laid out. +1

Comment: Thank you. Between this response and the response to another question I added several days ago, I have now got a good grip on autolayouts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result in your pictures, here is how to do it. You can choose to use wAny|hAny size class.

1. From top to bottom, set vertical spacing between each adjacent views to be 0.
2. Set height constraint for view1 and view3 and view4 to be a static value.

Then the height of view2 should vary on different screen sizes.

Looking from your picture, your view1 occupies almost half of the screen space. So my suggestion is to make its height to be proportional, you can set view1 and its superview to be equal width, then modify this equal width constraint's ratio to be 0.5. You can do the same for other views in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, with the visual format, it should look like smth like this

```
V:|[view1(HIGHTV1)][view2][HIGHT3(HIGHTV3)][view4(HIGHTV4)]|
```

Repalce `HIGHTVX` with the static sizes